# Mongod Command not recognized despite specifying Path

Tags: mongodb

Im getting the following error;

'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I've googled/read various threads and incorrect path seems to be common root cause.

However I have specified what appears to be correct path (tried both with and without quotation marks as you can see) ;

[image: path]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directories to the `PATH` variable. Click on the `Path` variable, then "Edit" and add 2 entries listed below. You then need to click "OK" twice for the changes to be fully saved.

- %Mongo%
- %Mongo2%

This references the two environment variables which you have created.

Notice: you may need to restart `cmd` before changes take effect.